# errors when using copyof method in java

Tags: java

I tried to use Java to enlarge one array using  `copyof()` method in Arrays class. As the document says, I predict the whole array should have 0 in every element.
 however, the error comes:`java.lang.NullPointerException`. I don't know why this error is coming. Do me a favor, please. Thank you.

```
int[][] ak = new int[2][3];
ak = Arrays.copyOf(ak, 90);
System.out.print(ak[20][1]);
```

Comment: Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(char[], int) again but a bit more Carefully

Comment: From javadocs: Throws:
    NegativeArraySizeException - if newLength is negative
    NullPointerException - if original is null

Comment: if your problem is solved by my answer  then you can select my answer

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.copyOf(T[] orig, int newLen)` doesn't make `n` copies - it will trim, or pad with `null`s, to get to the desired size.  So everything past `ak[2]` will be `null`.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29)

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if
>   necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that
>   are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
>   contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy
>   but not the original, the copy will contain null.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(int[] original,int newLength)` method copies the specified array, truncating or padding with zeros (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy but not the original, the copy will contain 0.Such indices will exist if and only if the specified length is greater than that of the original array.

Following is the declaration for `java.util.Arrays.copyOf()` method

```
public static int[] copyOf(int[] original,int newLength)
```

Here is an example:

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class ArrayDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // intializing an array arr1
    int[] arr1 = new int[] {45, 32, 75};

    // printing the array
    System.out.println("Printing 1st array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(arr1[i]);  
    }

    // copying array arr1 to arr2 with newlength as 5
    int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, 5);
    arr2[3] = 11;
    arr2[4] = 55;   

    // printing the array arr2
    System.out.println("Printing new array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) 
    {
      System.out.println(arr2[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

and output is:

```
Printing 1st array: 
45
32
75
Printing new array:
45
32
75
11
55
```